# What is easier for machine - dictionary comprehension or deepcopy of existing dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Initializing a function I need two same dictionaries, one of them I can only create with dict. comprehension. But when it came to second one I got curious if it is easier (less time and/or fewer operations) for machine to make it as a deepcopy of the first one or rather repeat the same comprehension.

I usually set both as comprehensions 'cause my dictionaries are generally small, but when there are not empty values and/or more keys it may matter.

```
# both as comprehensions (implying I already have keys)
dict1 = {key: [] for key in keys}
dict2 = {key: [] for key in keys}

# second one as a deepcopy of the first
dict1 = {key: [] for key in keys}
dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1)
```

Well, I don't expect big difference for my case but I am just curious how it works in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`deepcopy`  does *a lot* more work/checking than your first example, a simple timing exercise confirms this:

```
In [1]: import copy 
   ...:  
   ...: dict1 = {key: [] for key in 'abcdefgh'}    
   ...:  
   ...: %timeit dict2 = {key: [] for key in 'abcdefgh'} 
   ...:  
   ...: %timeit dict2 = copy.deepcopy(dict1) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
816 ns ± 5.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
21 µs ± 28.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

If you know in advance your data structure (i.e. the level of nesting and types etc.), then you can make decent performance gains by avoiding `deepcopy`. However, `deepcopy` is more flexible of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I would upvote if I had enough reputation)